# Initializing controls on NIB load - EXC_BAD_ACCESS on destruction

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I'm loading an overlay view from an xib in my storyboard / iOS6 / ARC app.  This view has an image view, text view and some switches.  My problem is that after customizing some of the controls, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to transition away from the view back to my main view.

I'm loading the view by creating an instance from my view controller (during a `button_touchup` function) and calling UIView `transitionWithView`.  I can initialize the `imageView` and `text` with data passed from the VC through an instance function that populates those controls.  This works fine and I can transition away no problem.

The problem comes in when I try to customize the switch colors - e.g. `_toggleSwitch.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorwithRed.....];`  The toggle shows up white and then crashes with bad_exec during interaction or on destruction of the view (when transitioning back to the main view / `self removeFromSuperview`).  I've tried doing this before I transition to the view with an instance function, I've tried doing it on `-awakeFromNib` and `-didMoveToWindow` without luck.  I've tried saving the colors in strong properties on the class.  The only thing that works is using a built in constant - e.g. `_toggleSwitch.thumbTintColor = [UIColor redColor]`.

How can I customize the appearance of these switches without crashing?  I even tried passing in the custom UIColor object from my presenting view controller through the overlay view's setup function the same way I'm passing in the text to `textfield.text` and the image to `imageview.image` - by assigning it to `self.toggleswitch.thumbTintColor` and it *still* causes a bad exec.  How do I customize the switches in my xib?

EDIT:Ok, I didn't think the code was all that revelatory, but here's the overlay

```
overlay.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switchFB;
```

This works fine in -awakeFromNib / anywhere else in the xib

```
Overlay.m
_switchFB.thumbTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This causes exc_bad_access

```
_switchFB.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:225.0f green:152.0f blue:140.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

The exception is thrown when I'm trying to transition back to the superview (or sometimes when interacting with the modified toggle):

```
- (IBAction)buttonCancelClick:(id)sender {
[UIView transitionWithView:self.superview
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [self removeFromSuperview];
                }
                completion:nil
     ];
}
```

I figured it has to do with memory access to the created UIColor object.  I don't have a problem accessing objects I pass into the Overlay to initialize the text an image views, so I modifed the setup function (called from the parentVC) that initializes those objects to initialize my switch as well.  This still crashes.

```
Overlay.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

Overlay.m
- (void)setup:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)txt color:(UIColor *)col
{
  self.switchFB.thumbTintColor = col;
  self.textField.text = txt;
  self.imageView.image = img;
}


ParentVC.m
OverlayPublish *olay = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayPublish"owner:self options:nil][0];
[olay setup:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] text:@"test txt" color:[UIColor colorWithRed:225.0f green:152.0f blue:140.0f alpha:1.0f]];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.superview.superview
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                animations:^{
                    [self.view.superview.superview addSubview:olay];
                }
                completion:nil
```

Edit2: stack trace - I went back to removeFromSuperView.

> - thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x01d8209b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x51019e21)
>
>   frame #0: 0x01d8209b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15
>
>   frame #1: 0x0224d41c CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 108
>
>   frame #2: 0x02272e54 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 196
>
>   frame #3: 0x01d849ff libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject release] + 47
>
>   frame #4: 0x01d73927 libobjc.A.dylib`ReleaseValue 
>     std::for_each<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation*, std::vector<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation, objc_references_support::ObjcAllocator<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation> > ,ReleaseValue>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation*, std::vector<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation, objc_references_support::ObjcAllocator<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation*, std::vector<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation, objc_references_support::ObjcAllocator<objc_references_support::ObjcAssociation> > >, ReleaseValue) + 72
>     frame #5: 0x01d73632 libobjc.A.dylib`_object_remove_assocations + 296
>
>   frame #6: 0x01d7a7aa libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 60
>
>   frame #7: 0x01d7a7cf libobjc.A.dylib`object_dispose + 20
>
>   frame #8: 0x00b2601a UIKit`-[UIImage dealloc] + 217
>
>   frame #9: 0x01d849ff libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject release] + 47
>
>   frame #10: 0x00c0df90 UIKit`-[UIImageView dealloc] + 752
>
>   frame #11: 0x00b4199c UIKit`-[UIView release] + 93
>
>   frame #12: 0x00b497fb UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 190
>
>   frame #13: 0x00b43ee5 UIKit`-[UIView dealloc] + 375
>
>   frame #14: 0x00d06a01 UIKit`-[_UISwitchInternalView dealloc] + 288
>
>   frame #15: 0x00b4199c UIKit`-[UIView release] + 93
>
>   frame #16: 0x00b497fb UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 190

Comment: Show the code, don't give a long, dense, description of the code.

Comment: I've tried to clean this up a little for readability, but it's still completely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Alright, I've added the code.

Comment: Could you add the stack trace after bad access please?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the SDK specific to UISwitch.  [UISwitch setThumbTintColor causing crash (iOS 6 only)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972500/uiswitch-setthumbtintcolor-causing-crash-ios-6-only)

Calling retain on a UIColor function variable before assigning it to the nib's UISwitch thumbTintColor property resolves the crash.

Comment: I hope you reported it to radar? That's a pretty nasty bug... especially sinec it seems to occur when ARC is enabled.